# Вход в систему с помощью OpenID в Android-приложении

Tags: openid, android, java

Я могу зайти в приложение по Google Open ID (на сервере поддержка реализована, работоспособна). Клиент работает на платформе Android. Вход в систему происходит таким образом: спрашиваем у сервера уникальный URI, по которому следует проследовать пользователю, и посылаем на этот URI запрос. Если пользователь в данной системе уже выполнил вход в Google Account, то открывается сессия для этого пользователя (в это время клиент проверяет появление текущей сессии). Иначе пользователю предоставляется страница входа в Google Account. Я пытаюсь реализовать это с помощью `WebView` таким образом:

```
WebView web = new WebView(context);
web.loadUrl(uniqUrlFromServer);
```

В итоге происходит что-то непонятное. На эмуляторе WebView открывает нужную страницу, но когда я ввожу имя и пароль и нажимаю "Sign In", то входа в Google Account не происходит, вместо этого открывается браузер (отдельное приложение). На устройстве `WebView` не открывает первоначальный URI вообще. URI для OpenID, конечно, не простой: HTTPS, с параметрами, с редиректами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, Вам нужно попробовать переопределить клиент для WebView. Примерно так:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, 
                               String failingUrl) {
   }

   @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
   }

});
```

И уже в этих методах реагировать при разборе URL как угодно. [Дока по WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). Ну и может поможет - [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330761/openid-for-android-apps-that-require-signin). Также, можно попробовать либу ответом выше.

Answer (score 0):

Есть библиотека: [openid4java](http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/).

> Эта библиотека позволяет добавить поддержку OpenID в ваше веб-приложение на Java.